# " Existing configuration file (./config.inc.php) is not readable. "?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, xampp, root

just installed XAMPP on my Mac. When I was trying to modify the upload dir in `config.inc.php` it says that the file was locked, and can't be unlocked due to the fact that I don't have permission to modify the folder. So I changed the my permission to the folder, and file was not locked anymore but I can't access 'phpmyadmin' anymore in my browser via `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`, everytime I try, it says `"Existing configuration file (./config.inc.php) is not readable."`

I googled the solution, from this [page](http://myeasylinux.wordpress.com/2010/07/31/phpmyadmin/), it says to use `chown root:cpanelphpmyadmin config.inc.php` to change the permission of the file. I did, but it says `chown: cpanelphpmyadmin: Invalid argument`in my terminal window. I am get desperate here, anyone help me, please!

by the way, I tried deleting everything in the XAMPP folder in App folder, and create a new one, it doesn't work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
rasel@rasel-Dell:~$ sudo -s
rasel@rasel-Dell:~$ type your password
root@rasel-Dell:/# cd /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
root@rasel-Dell:/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin# chmod 644 config.inc.php
root@rasel-Dell:/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin# cd /
root@rasel-Dell: /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

That's all, it works for me.

Comment: can you explain to me the used of -> chmod 644?

Answer (score 10):

For OSX Mavericks and XAMPP 1.8.2-5 and 1.8.3-4 versions, you need to use the same chmod 644 mentioned above, but the directory is different.

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/
sudo chmod 644 config.inc.php
[enter your password]
```

Comment: It shows me an error after writing `sudo chmod 777 config.inc.php` 
Error: `chmod: Unable to change file mode on config.inc.php: Operation not permitted`

Comment: This may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932609/unable-to-edit-config-inc-php

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/
sudo chmod 777 config.inc.php
[enter your password]
```

After you change your `config.inc.php`, you need to type:

```
sudo chmod 644 config.inc.php
```

Only `sudo chmod 644` didnt work for me.

Comment: It shows me an error after writing `sudo chmod 777 config.inc.php` 
Error: `chmod: Unable to change file mode on config.inc.php: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by creating a new config.inc.php file, copying all of the original locked config.inc.php content there and modifying the line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'myserverpassword';
```

and deleting the original locked file. This is in case you are looking for changing the XAMPP configuration file so that you can access the servers where you have put a new password.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using ubuntu 14.04 what you actually need to do is:

1. Go to terminal
2. type -->  sudo nautilus
3. a file dialogue will be opened.
4. navigate the folder to computer/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
5. open the file
6. check for $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
7. change the above LOC to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';

and try opening the phpmy admin. Your problem will be successfully solved.