# Unable to Edit config.inc.php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

Running: macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3, zsh w/ iTerm2

Trying to set up a local environment with **xampp**, which has worked just fine for me in the past.  However, I'm now unable to access **phpmyadmin** after changing the root password via the **phpmyadmin** UI.

[image]

The tutorial I am following (which suggested doing this) pointed me to the **config.inc.php** file, where the password variable would also need to be updated.  Unfortunately, I am unable to edit this file.  I've seen other users in Stack Overflow complain of the same issue, but the answer that comes back always seems to involve editing via **vi** or **nano**, which doesn't work for me either.  Here's an example of what happens when using nano.

I open file via nano

```
sudo nano config.inc.php
```

My terminal then prompts me for the system password.

Once in nano, I navigate to the password variable and enter it:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '[mypassword]';`

I then attempt to save using ctrl+O, where I'm prompted:

`File Name to Write: config.inc.php`

and then after hitting ENTER receive the error from nano:

`Error writing config.inc.php: Permission denied`

I've also tried to editing the file via **Sublime Text 3**, where my machine prompts me to enter the user password.  I receive no error message after doing that, but still cannot access **phpmyadmin**.  I am unable to use chmod to edit permissions on the file, and restarting the mysql server after editing the **config.inc.php** file also does not work.

Why is nano throwing the "permission denied" error even after I've entered my system password?

Thanks!

Comment: `chmod 775 config.inc.php` then try editing, or try with sudo if you still don't have permission

Comment: This operation results in: `chmod: Unable to change file mode on config.inc.php: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Okay try with sudo, use your mac password. `sudo chmod 775 config.inc.php`

Comment: I receive the identical error message when adding `sudo`

Comment: `ls -la config.inc.php`. Paste the output

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 daemon  daemon  5109 Aug 21 16:28 config.inc.php` -- Thanks for all the help! @delboy1978uk

Comment: so it belongs to user daemon in group daemon, only the owner can read and write, the group and everyone else can only read. It's very strange that `sudo` doesn't help though, as it makes commands run as root! Try `sudo chown yourmacusername config.inc.php` to change the owner. Then try the permissions. Also, find out which user your PHP actually operates as

Comment: worst comes to the worst, copy the content, delete the file, and create a new one with the same name

Comment: BTW, Sequel Pro is a million times better than PHPMyAdmin when on a Mac, have a look! https://sequelpro.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, attempting to change ownership results in `chown: config.inc.php: Operation not permitted`, and I am unable to delete the file after coping out its contents (`rm: config.inc.php: Permission denied`).  Thanks for the tip on sequelpro.com, I'll look into that

Comment: these comments werent helpfull :( it still doesnt work

Answer (score 14):

I was able to resolve this by accessing the config.inc.php file via the terminal provided by xampp.

[image]

First things first, the xampp-provided terminal needed nano (to edit the file) installed.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nano
```

I then navigated to the file:

```
cd ../opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
```

Then opened the file with nano:

```
nano config.inc.php
```

or try

sudo nano config.inc.php

This finally allowed me to edit the config.inc.php file and successfully save.

Comment: I'm curious how are you using apt-get on MacOS?

Comment: I simply ran the two commands via the xampp terminal, as explained above.  I'm guessing this particular terminal uses Linux, as the shell prompt reads: **root@debian:~#**

Comment: TLDR; The solution is to use XAMPP's built-in terminal. I was trying to access the mounted drive through finder, and you cannot update the permissions. You HAVE to use the built-in terminal opened through the app, and you can use nano or vi to update the config.inc.php file.

Comment: Perfect @ChrisBalow I was really pissed off your solution works. Great Thanks

Comment: 900iq i was bashing my head for 8 hours

Comment: Everyone note: in this answer VM xampp is used, not a local one. In local you dont have terminal button and no linux shell

Answer (score 1):

Great question. I had to work on this for an hour to figure it out too.

Open Xaamp and go to "Open Terminal" on the main page. Make sure the server is running.

You can run "apt-get update" like the other person said above me. The main one you want is "apt-get install nano"

Then do "cd .." so you can back out of the file. The other person said "cd ../opt/... " but that command didn't work for me. What worked was doing "cd .."

Then do cd again, type in "cd opt/lampp/phpmyadmin"

Then type "nano config.inc.php"

You should now be able to edit it. Hit control + o to save it.

It worked for me. It took me an hour to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, I have the same issue as the above, I tried all the commands and I have changed the config.inc file into these settings :

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

But I still end by the same error when I'm acceding to phpmyadmin

Any solutions please ??

Answer (score 0):

**Try this to edit the file:**

Open terminal from Xampp -> enter `apt-get update` then -> enter`apt-get install nano` then -> navigated to the file `cd ../opt/lampp/phpmyadmin` -> open the file `nano config.inc.php` make changes as you like -> to save, press `control + O` and `control + M` and to exit -> `control + X`

**You might not need to edit the file to solve the error. just try this:**

Open terminal from Xampp -> enter `apt-get update` then -> enter`apt-get install nano` then -> navigated to mysql folder `cd ../opt/lampp/var/mysql` -> delete these files `rm ib_logfile0` enter and -> `rm ib_logfile1` enter

now restart Xampp.