# phpMyAdmin error message " The $cfg['TempDir'] (./tmp/) is not accessible."

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using XAMPP on my Mac, but phpMyAdmin gives me an error " The $cfg['TempDir'] (./tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able to cache templates and will be slow because of this."

I tried to create a tmp folder or modify the `config.inc.php` under phpMyAdmin but it was not allowed. I got an error saying "Could not add write permission to the file because you do not own it. Try modifying the permissions of the file in the Finder or Terminal."
I also checked in the terminal with "whoami" and I was the admin user.

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are the admin user but it doesn't mean that the running application has admin permissions. The best thing to do is alter the permissions on the parent folder to allow the application to make changes to it. Giving admin permissions to applications is hardly a good idea.

Comment: @AndreFeijo I tried to alter the permissions on the parent folder but it wouldn't allow me, it gave an error message "The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission."

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by altering config.inc.php in the terminal from XAMPP, following the answer of this question [Unable to Edit config.inc.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932609/unable-to-edit-config-inc-php)